# Save Button Colour on local storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Im quite new to web development. i have seen similar questions, but it did not help me.

I have a button and it turns green when i press it. But when the page refreshes, the colour disappears. I know local storage is a solution to this but i don't know how to implement it. i tried so many times with local storage but couldn't figure out a solution .  i have posted my HTML code below. Note that my button is inside a form , because i need to access a link from my button. How can i save the button colour with local storage so that the colour doesn't disappear when the page refreshes. And if i put a second button i want the colour to disappear from the first button, so that only the second button is active. Any help is truly appreciated. Any examples done on my code would also help !!Thanks a lot for your time.

```
HTML code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style>
.button {

box-shadow: -2px 2px blanchedalmond, -1px 1px orange, -1px 1px orange;
margin-top: 280px; 
margin-left: 420px;    
background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128); 

  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 35px;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

.button:focus{

background-color:rgba(10, 170, 10, 0.952);
}

</style>
</head>


<body>

  <div style = "position:fixed; left:-300px; top:-100px;">


<form method="get" action="http://1.1.1.1/myfile.php" >
<button class="button">Lights On</button>
</form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage.setItem(key, value)` and `localStorage.getItem(key)`. Here's an example that adds an event handler to the form to save in localStorage that the button was pressed, and on page load, mark the color green if it finds that localStorage indicator:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
    .button {
      box-shadow: -2px 2px blanchedalmond, -1px 1px orange, -1px 1px orange;
      margin-top: 280px; 
      margin-left: 420px;    
      background-color:rgb(128, 128, 128); 

      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 30px 35px;

      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 16px;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
    }

    .button-green, .button:focus {
      background-color:rgba(10, 170, 10, 0.952);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style = "position:fixed; left:-300px; top:-100px;">
    <form id="form" method="get" action="https://1.1.1.1/myfile.php" >
      <button class="button">Lights On</button>
    </form>
    
    <script>
        if (localStorage.getItem('formSubmitted') === 'yes') {
            for(const button of document.getElementsByClassName('button')) {
                button.classList.add('button-green')
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
            localStorage.setItem('formSubmitted', 'yes');
        })
    </script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey @ Ezekiel Elin. I tried the code.  When i press the button and the request goes through to the server, but the problem now is when i add another button called "lights off" both the buttons are green when one button is pressed. I wanted the colour of one button to go when another is pressed. Thanks much!!!

Comment: You'll need to set different values in localStorage based on which button is pressed, and check each one appropriately when you reload the page. In this case, you'd also need to specify a unique ID for each button and do `document.getElementById('button-id').classList.add('button-green')` so that it only applies to the one button.

Comment: Hey @Ezekial Elin. I tried it, but could not get it to work. The colour still stays in button 2. Will you please be able to show me how it works :( . Don't know where I'm going wrong.